# radial blur/grayscale/filters in kineticjs possible?

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I've an image on which there are several hotspots. A nice effect that could be applied would be to keep some circular region around the hotspot as it is and progressively apply a filter. It is easy to apply a fill gradient, but I would rather like to apply a filter like blur or grayscale. Is this possible with KineticJs? Low level methods dealing directly with context will also do.

This is what I'm currently able to achieve:

[image: img]